# How to specify the document from which to access data?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data of Users from a document, whose ID was generated by firebase. However, I do not know how do I get the reference to which document to look into. [An image of firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLv0.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the ID of the document ahead of time, your only option is to [query for it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) using the value of one of its fields.  If you can't find the document with a query, your only other option is to read the entire collection (using a query with no filters) and iterate the documents in the result until you're able to find the one you're looking for.